# How to replace a value from a select() method in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a model called 'GearItem' that has rows of gear items. One of the columns is called 'manufacturer_id'. - These are the id's of the 'Manufacturer' model that holds the data about the manufacturer of each gear item.

I have created a function in my GearItem controller called "getItemsNames" and I want it to return a JSON that will look like so:

```
[
{id: 1,
name: "foo",
manufacturer: "bar"}, 
{id: 2,
name: "baz",
manufacturer: "qux"},
{...}, 
]
```

How do I change the query
 `GearItem::select('id', 'name', 'manufacturer_id')->get();`

to replace the  `'manufacturer_id'` by `$manufacturer[0]->name` after I define:

```
$manufacturer = Manufacturer::select('name')
                            ->where('id', GearItem::value('manufacturer_id'))
                            ->get();
```

I don't know how to insert this logic without breaking the JSON structure. Is there an elegant way to do it or do I have to iterate through the JSON and replace every `'manufacturer_id'` by the name?

Comment: can you please post the controller code?

Comment: You write a JOIN with the Manufacturer table and get the Manufacturers name out of the manufacturer

Comment: @Berto99 for now, the controller does nothing more than the select query.

Comment: @RiggsFolly where do I insert the JOIN? before the `->get();` in the GearItem select query?

Comment: i'm sorry, what is `$manufacturer[0]`? you want to give every `GearItem` the same `manufacturer`? because if you hardcode `[0]` you will ends up with all the `GearItem` with the same manufacturer name

Comment: @Berto99 the $manufacturer returns this structure: [{name: "foo"}] if I want to extract only the name i need to call `$manufacturer[0]->name` to get through the parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the tip from RiggsFolly helped me find the most elegant solution, that  would be a
`->join()` method after the select. This solved the problem:

```
GearItem::select('gear_items.id', 'gear_items.name', 'manufacturers.name as manufacturer')
        ->join('manufacturers', 'gear_items.manufacturer_id', '=', 'manufacturers.id')
        ->get();
```